# Files & Database Automatic Synchronisation

Tags: mysql, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api, data-synchronization, offlineapps

I have to realise an web travel guide for our trains.

On the one hand, I have the **backend**, based on the Wordpress API, where the user can add and modify content. This site is hosted on a simple public server.

On the second hand, I have the **frontend**, a progressive web app based on the  Wordpress API, where the user can see the content. This webapp is hosted on a Raspberry Pi accessible from a hotspot in a no network place.

One is always **online**, the other is almost always **offline**.

I think the Wordpress API should be installed on the both, but I don't know how can I synchronise the backend modification (MySQL Database and maybe WP files) with the offline PWA each time the hotspot has a internet connection.

Anyone has an idea ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Firstly !
Have the API on your hand with access to Database , Have Same Connection of Database on both End's  , so you can have your database synced !

Comment: I already have the same connection of Database. My question is how can I synchronise automatically each time the Pi has a internet connection.